# Replace spaces in all URLs with %20 using Regex

Tags: php, regex, bbedit

I have a large block of HTML that contains multiples URLs with spaces in them. How do I used Regex to replace any space that occurs in a URL, with a '%20'. The good thing is that all of the URLs end with '.pdf'.

Looking for something I could run in BBedit/Text Wrangler, or even PHP.

Example: `http://www.site-name.com/dir/file name here.pdf`

Need to return: `http://www.site-name.com/dir/file%20name%20here.pdf`

Comment: Technically, spaces (especially in URLs) is not recommended.  Here is a good read as to "why" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093611/why-shouldnt-i-use-spaces-in-file-names-when-i-can-use-a-code-equivalent

Comment: You need to show us more patterns and your attempts. Full sample input is a good point to start with.

Comment: You could examine this: [Replace specified character between two strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152621/replace-specified-character-between-two-strings)

Comment: How did you generate this HTML? Is this for a 1-shot?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Regex you could use could use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) in PHP to achieve this which escapes the url for you. Similar to [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) in JavaScript.

Comment: True. But I have a large chunk of HTML that with hundreds of URLs containing spaces. I'd like to clean them up. Use Regex to find strings starting with 'http' and ending with '.pdf' and replace any spaces with between those elements with a %20.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with exactly the same problem. I solved it with this:

```
    $text = preg_replace("/http(.*) (.*)\.pdf/U", "http$1%20$2.pdf", $text);
```

This looks for a space between http and pdf and then replaces the space with %20.

If your URLs have multiple spaces, then simply run the code over and over until all the spaces are gone:

```
    while(preg_match("/http(.*) (.*)\.pdf/U", $text))
    {
            $text = preg_replace("/http(.*) (.*)\.pdf/U", "http$1%20$2.pdf", $text);
            echo('testing testing');
    }
```

However, I've found this will overwrite text if there are two or more URLs on the same line. I haven't found a solution for this yet.